# Make specific div appear before another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

As of link: https://www.fermento24.com/collections/all?pf_t_premi=Premio+Vitae&pf_t_premi_and_condition=true

I have these icons with class="tag boost-pfs-filter-label categories important", and I'd like these to appear BEFORE the other icons class="tag boost-pfs-filter-label premi important boost-pfs-action-overlay".

Can't change it by html because they're generated by a js (see js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/morganpubblicita/d93czaeg/) and even if I try and move the categorie section on top here, it just doesn't show them.

I tried to give the premi tag the "absolute" and "top:100%" but then they will stack on top of each other.

Any way to solve this problem?

```html
<div class="boost-pfs-filter-product-item-label"><span class="sale boost-pfs-filter-label"> Sconto </span><span class="tag boost-pfs-filter-label premi important boost-pfs-action-overlay">
  <span class="grade">5</span>
  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/0383/0855/t/12/assets/bibenda.svg?v=969584104512111952">
  <span class="tooltip boost-pfs-action-overlay">
    <b>Premio Bibenda:</b><br>Annata: 2018 – Punteggio <img src="link"><img src="link"><img src="link"><img src="link"><br><i>Vino leggendario</i>
  </span>
</span><span class="tag boost-pfs-filter-label premi important boost-pfs-action-overlay">
  <span class="grade">3</span>
  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/0383/0855/t/12/assets/gamberorosso.svg?v=4883056955815699697">
  <span class="tooltip">
    <b>Premio Gambero rosso:</b><br>Annata: 2019 – Punteggio di 3 su 3<br><i>Vino eccellente</i>
  </span>
</span><span class="tag boost-pfs-filter-label premi important boost-pfs-action-overlay">
  <span class="grade">2</span>
  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/0383/0855/t/12/assets/slowwine.svg?v=13534204178531355278">
  <span class="tooltip">
    <b>Premio Vino Slow:</b><br>Annata: 2019 – Punteggio di 91 su 100<br><i>Vino Eccellente con caratteri legati al territorio</i>
  </span>
</span><span class="tag boost-pfs-filter-label categories important">
 <a href="/collections/all/products/cerasuolo-dabruzzo-2019-emidio-pepe" class="boost-pfs-filter-product-item-title boost-pfs-action-overlay"> <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/0383/0855/t/12/assets/prezzo.svg?v=2402614121362096238" title="Rapporto qualita prezzo">
  </a></span><span class="tag boost-pfs-filter-label categories important">
 <a href="/collections/all/products/cerasuolo-dabruzzo-2019-emidio-pepe" class="boost-pfs-filter-product-item-title boost-pfs-action-overlay"> <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/0383/0855/t/12/assets/romantica.svg?v=4990615261420446289" title="Vino per una cena romantica">
  </a></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch the order in the JS code.

```
 var premiLabel = '';

 var categoriesLabel = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < data.tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = data.tags[i];
        if (tag.indexOf("categories_Rapporto qualità/prezzo") !== -1) {
          if (tag.indexOf("important") !== -1) {
            var prezzoLabel = boostPFSTemplate.prezzoLabelHtml.replace(/{{prezzoGrade}}/g, tag.split('_')[2]).replace(/{{prezzoClass}}/g, "important");
          } else {
            var prezzoLabel = boostPFSTemplate.prezzoLabelHtml.replace(/{{prezzoGrade}}/g, tag.split('_')[2]).replace(/{{prezzoClass}}/g, "unimportant");
          }
          premiLabel += prezzoLabel;

......


 for (var i = 0; i < data.tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = data.tags[i];
        if (tag.indexOf("premi_Gambero Rosso") !== -1) {
          if (tag.indexOf("important") !== -1) {
            var gamberoRossoLabel = boostPFSTemplate.gamberoRossoLabelHtml.replace(/{{gamberoRossoDescription}}/g, tag.split('_')[3]).replace(/{{gamberoRossoGrade}}/g, tag.split('_')[2]).replace(/{{gamberoRossoClass}}/g, "important");
          } else {
            var gamberoRossoLabel = boostPFSTemplate.gamberoRossoLabelHtml.replace(/{{gamberoRossoDescription}}/g, tag.split('_')[3]).replace(/{{gamberoRossoGrade}}/g, tag.split('_')[2]).replace(/{{gamberoRossoClass}}/g, "unimportant");
          }
          premiLabel += gamberoRossoLabel;

.....
```

Comment: It...Works... But I don't get the logic. Why should I move only the content without var premiLabel = ''; for it to work?

Comment: From the code, it is populating `premiLabel` with `premiLabel += item`.  So just switch the populating order and voila